# How do I log in to Mint when I've forgotten my password?

Tags: password

I installed Mint 17.1, but I can't remember the log in password. Is there a way of disabling it?

Comment: http://mintguide.org/system/248-reset-the-password-for-root-or-any-user-in-linux-mint.html  Either that or a similar procedure. It varies depending on version and I didn't see anything specific to 17.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's a bit technical, but you can log in without knowing the password.

Boot the laptop. You'll get the GRUB screen for selecting your operating system before Linux boots. With the default option selected, press e. This will let you edit the script that boots the OS (not permanently).

Use the arrow keys to go to the line that starts with "kernel" or "linux", and add `rw init=/bin/bash` to the end.

Press the key to boot. I believe this is F10, but it's shown on the screen.

You will end up logged in at a command prompt. Enter `passwd <username>` to change the password for the account with that username.

Reboot the computer, by entering `reboot`. You can now log in with the new password.

I don't have a Linux Mint installation available at the moment, but I remember there's a place in the settings to make it log in automatically.

Comment: k, none of the lines start with kernel. in fact, the word is not in any of the lines :(

Comment: It seems that it can also start with "linux". I edited it in.

Comment: I guess the only thing to do with this pos is format it & go back to windows. Didn't wanna do that but, like I said, I know totally nothing about Linux & at this point, I'm not so sure that I wanna learn.

Comment: If all else fails, it's easier to reinstall Linux Mint than to put Windows on it. This is not typical for a Linux experience - you're trying to fix a problem that you're not supposed to be able to fix.

Comment: Ok, how do I go about re installing it? Like I said, I know nothing about Linux

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Linux-Mint is a good guide, but it doesn't tell you how to install from a usb drive, which is also an option. To do that, get YUMI from http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/. Use the program to put the ISO on a usb drive. On some computers, it doesn't automatically boot from the installation media. In that case, while booting, press the key it displays on the screen for getting to the boot menu. Use trial and error to select the right option if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the info & all of your help. Hoping that I'll get to use this lappy at long last.